# getting exception while opening custom popup on mouse click

Tags: javafx-2

I have one package name `com.soarite` which containing SOARiteController class and two fxml file like soaritemain.fxml and custom_control.fxml.

I have one tree in soaritemain.fxml. I am trying to show popup on mouseclick on that tree. or want to show only two menu.

Here is my code.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/com/soarite/custom_control.fxml"));
    //fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(null);
    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
```

And here is my custom_control.fxml.

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" minHeight="119.5" prefHeight="119.5" prefWidth="188.0" styleClass="mainFxmlClass" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="com.soarite.SOARiteController">
<children>
<VBox layoutX="33.0" layoutY="35.0" prefHeight="73.0" prefWidth="100.0">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="treeOpenTestBed" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleOpenTestBedTree" text="Open TestBed" />
    <Button fx:id="treeNewTestBed" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleNewTestBedTree" text="New TestBed" />
  </children>
</VBox>
</children>
<stylesheets>
<URL value="@main.css" />
</stylesheets>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here exception details which i am getting.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2021)
at com.soarite.SOARiteController.MouseClickedOnTree(SOARiteController.java:224)
```

I don't understand how to do this.  Is this i am doing right or e need to do something else. I am newbie on JavaFx.

Comment: The code does not provide enough information to reproduce the problem, but the `setLocation(null)` part certainly looks suspicious. Try removing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
fxmlLoader.setLocation(null);
```

is causing the exception you see. The location is the resource representing the fxml file which is to be loaded; so if you set it to null the loader doesn't know where to find the file. Remove this line.

This will give you another exception. You are also setting the controller "by hand" with the line

```
fxmlLoader.setController(this);
```

and then your fxml file itself specifies a controller with the fx:controller attribute in the root element. You cannot specify a controller in fxml if the controller is already set on the FXMLLoader. You probably want to remove the setController(...) call in the Java code.